# How to filter store by few items

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch

Can enyone help me?
I need to filter store items by some ids.
I have a store and a model for it:

```
Ext.regModel('rt.models.Situation', {
        fields: [
            { name: 'sitId', type: 'int' },
            { name: 'sitName', type: 'string' },
            { name: 'typeId', type: 'int' }
        ]
    });
```

and I need to filter my store by ids like this
`var filterIds=[1,2,3];`

`store.filter('typeId', filterIds);`
but it is not working.
When I use only one id for filtering it works fine, but with array of ids it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this situation you need to use [`store.filterBy(fn)`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-filterBy) method and supply your own filtering function (`fn`) that will test if id is contained in the `filterIds` array.